# Is there any issue with setting a ridiculous height (such as 10000px) instead of using height 100%?

Tags: html, css

I needed to set the height of an element to cover the whole page, but setting the height of the parent to 100% would ruin the layout. At first I used position: fixed to ameliorate the problem, but that broke down when I used a css3 transform. I've now resorted to `height: 10000px`. Are there any potential problems that could be caused by a hack like this?

Comment: I wound't do it this way. It can become troublesome down the line. Post your code or a link to your site.

Comment: You can set height 100% and then add actual window height by jQuery or javascript if you need exact height of webpage.

Comment: How would I go about adding height using javascript?

Comment: If you want folks to try to actually solve your issue without using the giant height, then you'd have to show us exactly what you are trying to do (code, CSS, detailed explanation, jsFiddle, etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with setting a giant height as long as it doesn't cause an unwanted scroll bar somewhere or influence the layout of some other element in an undesirable way.